# How do I save an image to a RTF formatted file?

Tags: java, image, rtf, jtextpane

I have a problem, in that I am able to save text to an RTF file, and also able to insert an image to the file, but when I save the file and load it again the image is not displaying. I have tried to use base64 to solve this problem but that didn't work.  What can I do to make it possible to save an image into an RTF file, and have it displayed when the file is re-opened?

This is my code:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
int option = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        image = Scalr.resize(image, 200);
        document = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();
        javax.swing.text.Style style = document.addStyle("StyleName",
                null);
        StyleConstants.setIcon(style, new ImageIcon(image));
        document.insertString(document.getLength(), "ignored text",
                style);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if (option == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
    fileChooser.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html instead of default one